# Product of set elements not exceeding a bound

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

I have a set of distinct positive integers `l` (if you wish, you may assume it is a list ordered by size), and a bound `lim`. In general, `l` has thousands of elements, but all are at most equal to `lim`. I would like to retrieve the set of all products of elements of `l` that do not exceed `lim`. That is, I'd like an efficient way of executing the following:

```
Select[ Times @@@ Subsets[lst] , #<=lim & ]
```

The only thing I have approaching a solution (other than the above, which is clearly not workable) is a rather complicated recursive implementation that is not very efficient.

Comment: Are you able to give rough values for `lim` and the max integers in `l`? (Also I assume we assume the integers are all positive?)

Comment: Depending on `l` and `lim`, you might first `Select[l, #<=lim]`, and then use your `Subsets` approach (so I second @Quantum_Oli 's question).

Comment: Yes, the integers are all positive and at most equal to `lim`.

Comment: For the use-cases you are interested in, is `Length[l]` typically only a bit smaller than `lim` (`l` is "dense") or is `lim` much, much larger (`l` is "sparse")? I.e. what is a typical value for `Length[l]/lim`?

Comment: `l` is definitely sparse. For example, when `lim`=10^8, `Length[l]/lim` is about 0.003. (A word: clearly this is part of another problem. I've chosen not to post the real problem because I'm trying to solve a Project Euler problem, and my solution path leads me in this direction. If it's wrong, it's wrong, but I want to find that out for myself.)

Comment: You might want to generate the subsets a few at a time; look up `NextSubset[]` and related functions in *Combinatorica*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun problem! Here is another recursive implementation. Note that I'm assuming that the input `l` is sorted and duplicate-free, like OP describes, i.e. `Union[l] == l` is `True`.

```
prods[l_, lim_] := 
 Block[{list = l, len = Length@l, storage = ConstantArray[0, Length@l]},
  Reap[
    Do[storage[[1]] = list[[i]];
     prodsRec[1, i, Quotient[lim, list[[i]]]]
     , {i, len}
     ]
    ][[2, 1]]
  ]

prodsRec[factorInd_, listPos_, lim_] := Block[{j = listPos + 1},
  Sow[storage[[1 ;; factorInd]]];
  While[j <= len && list[[j]] <= lim,
   storage[[factorInd + 1]] = list[[j]];
   prodsRec[factorInd + 1, j, Quotient[lim, list[[j]]]];
   j++
   ]
  ]
```

Looks more procedural than perhaps is usual around here, but should be pretty fast. Very little list manipulation means very little copying of lists due to *Mathematica* lists being immutable.

Testing one dense and one slightly sparse situation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length[prods[Range[100], 100]]]
```

> > {0.005645, 539}

```
rand = Union[RandomInteger[10000, 300]];
Length[rand]
```

> > 299

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length[prods[rand, 10000]]]
```

> > {0.003750, 399}

An example closer to what OP describes in comments:

```
rand2 = Union@RandomInteger[10^8, 10^8*3/1000];
Length[rand2]
```

> > 299 563

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length[bigExample = prods[rand2, 10^8]]]
```

> > {3.114989, 311 435}

Since the numbers in `rand2` are sampled uniformly from `Range[10^8]`, it's no surprise almost all products with two or more factors is **waaaay** larger than 10^8, so most "products" have only one factor:

```
Tally[Length /@ bigExample]
```

> > {{1, 299 563}, {2, 11 828}, {3, 44}}

It's much harder when the allowed factors are all "small":

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length[smallFactors = prods[Range[300], 10^5]]]
```

> > {14.771860, 1 470 607}

```
Tally[Length /@ smallFactors]
```

> > {{1, 300}, {2, 44 850}, {3, 344 016}, {4, 598 930}, {5, 384 643}, {6, 
> >       91 472}, {7, 6 345}, {8, 51}}

Comment: Nice solution. It is indeed fast. Unfortunately, I am interested in a limit of 10^12, and even this solution isn't fast enough. It appears that there are no non-recursive clever solutions, though I'll wait another day to see. If that's true, I'll have to find another approach. Thanks (+1).

Comment: I guess one would need to know more about the elements of `l` in order to proceed, if there is a pattern etc. I would be surprised if the number of valid products isn't huge for 10^12, haha.

Answer (score 3):

a recursive implementation.

```
test[ list_, rem_ /; (Length@rem > 0), lim_] := Module[{next, r},
   next = Select[ {Append[list, #], Complement[rem, {#}]} & /@ rem , 
     (Times @@ #[[1]] <= lim) &];
   (Sow[#[[1]]]; test[#[[1]], #[[2]], lim]) & /@ next];
Union[Sort /@ Reap[test[{}, Range[10], 10]][[2, 1]]]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {1, 2}, {1, 
>     3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {1, 10}, {2, 
>     3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}}

```
Select[Subsets[Range[10]], Times @@ # <= 10 &][[2 ;;]] == %
```

> True

A bigger example, (This will break the `Subsets` approach )

```
 Union[Sort /@ Reap[test[{}, Range[100], 100]][[2, 1]]] // 
   Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.31678, 539}